How to run multiple test cases using single driver instance of chrome in Karate UI
I need to login once and carry on with all scenarios at end needs logout
there is no direct provision it seems and no workaround i found.
driveroptions: stop: false can only prevent for driver closing but not using the same for other scenario's
do we have any other options?
tried: driveroption, callonce, before/after.
